# backup a greenplum instance: custom script

Tags: backup, greenplum

We have a greenplum 6.x instance. About 40 segment servers.
We have to backup the instance.
I know there are two main methods to backup greenplum instance

1. gpbackup for parallel backup. The main recommended method as I understand.
2. pg_dump non parallel backup that has to go through the master. (Not recommended because of slow performance) pg_dump and pg_restore is available for compatibility   with standard postgres databases.   (pg_dump / pg_restore)

But we cannot use a gpbackup: we do not have free space to keep a backup files. There is no enough free space on greenplum servers. And yet we don't have S3, NAS shared folder or data domain.
The only way that - theoretically - we have is to backup directories /pgdata/  - on all servers of the greenplum instance.

So the idea: perform a pg_start_backup command - copy entire directory /pgdata/ - copy WAL files to keep the backup consistency.

But I cannot understand how to perform a pg_start_backup command - on all PostgreSQL instances - members of the greenplum instance

Answer (score 0):

i'm confused how you have enough space to copy the entire pgdata and WAL files but do not have space to do a backup? Considering that you seem to believe backups are important (which they are if this is a critical system), there must be a way to cobble some storage either via NFS or S3 (cloudian or minio would work here) to do a proper gpbackup - it will save you a ton of time should you ever need to use this backup.